# drawImage is not working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawimage

```
var canvas = null;
var context = null;
var img = null;
var frames = [];
var assets = [];
var imgLoadCount = 0;

setup = function (fileArray) {
  assets = fileArray;
  //Loading an image
  for(var i = 0; i < assets.length; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    frames.push(new Image()); // declare image object
    frames[i].onload = onImageLoad(assets.length); //declare onload method
    frames[i].src = URL.createObjectURL(assets[i]); //set url 
  }
};

onImageLoad = function (len) {
  console.log("IMAGE!!!");
  canvas = document.getElementById("my_canvas"); //creates a canvas element
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth; //for full screen
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  var x, y, numTilesRow;
  numTilesRow = 10;
  imgLoadCount++;
  console.log("imgLoadCount = " + frames.length + ", length = " + len);
  if(imgLoadCount != len) {
    return;
  }
  for(var index = 0; index < len; index++) {
    x = Math.floor((index % numTilesRow));
    y = Math.floor(index / numTilesRow);
    worldX = x * numTilesRow;
    worldY = y * numTilesRow;
    context.drawImage(frames[index], worldX, worldY);
  }
};
```

I cant tell why drawImage has suddenly stopped working after inserting the code 
if(imgLoadCount != len) {return;} that makes sure that all images are properly loaded.  Would some one please help me find a solution to this problem.

Comment: Stupid question but did you check to see that `imgLoadCount == len`?

Comment: Yes, the for loop below runs only when imgLoad === len that is when all the images are loaded, thus drawImage is expected to draw an image in each run of the loop but it does not. And that is where i need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to understand the difference between a function reference and a function call. The `.onload` property expects to be assigned with a function reference, but you assign it with the return value of the immediate(!) call to the function `.onImageLoad`. The difference is the parentheses `()`.

If you want to call a function with parameters as a callback to `.onload`, then you'd have to include it into an anonymous function (which itself is a function reference)

```
frames[i].onload = function() {onImageLoad(assets.length);};
```

With this, of course, you create a closure. This means that at the point of execution the `onImageLoad()` method will have access to the current value of `assets.length` (and not to the value at the point of assignment!). But in your case this doesn't make any difference, because `assets.length` never changes.